# react native pass props to another component

Tags: react-native

I've been struggling passing a value from one component to another. It's a continuation of the issue from a previous question which was partially resolved: [react-native tab navigator search box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143614/react-native-tab-navigator-search-box)

I'm using tab navigator and here's my app setup:

index.js (renders tab setup)

router.js

searchHeader.js

tab1.js

tab2.js

etc

In index.js when a tab is changed I'm getting the name of the tab. I want to pass that to searchHeader.js to update the placeholder text.

As searchHeader.js isn't imported into index.js and not a direct child how do I pass it that value?

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Root, Tabs } from './config/router';
import { Alert,View } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {


constructor(props) {
super(props);
 this.state = {
searchText: '',
 }
}

_getCurrentRouteName(navState) {

if (navState.hasOwnProperty('index')) {
    this._getCurrentRouteName(navState.routes[navState.index])
} else {
    if (navState.routeName==='One') {
        this.setState({searchText:'Search One'})
    }
    if (navState.routeName==='Two') {
        this.setState({searchText:'Search Two'})
    }
    if (navState.routeName==='Three') {

        this.setState({searchText:'Search Three'})
    }
    if (navState.routeName==='Four') {
        this.setState({searchText:'Search Four'})
    }
}

}
 render() {
return ( 
    <Root onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, newState) => {
        this._getCurrentRouteName(newState)
    }} />

    )


  }
}

export default App;
```

router.js

```
...    

export const Root = StackNavigator({
 Tabs: {
screen: Tabs,
navigationOptions: {
header: <SearchHeader data={'Test'} />
  }
  },
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
});
```

searchHeader.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,Text,Dimensions,Alert } from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

class SearchHeader extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
super(props);
     this.state = {
  placeholder: "Search One"
     }

}


render() {
  return (
<SearchBar
  noIcon
  containerStyle={{backgroundColor:'#fff'}}
  inputStyle={{backgroundColor:'#e3e3e3',}}
  lightTheme = {true}
  round = {true}
  placeholder={data}
  placeholderTextColor = '#000'
/>
  );
}

};

export default SearchHeader;
```

Comment: A code example will help.

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: You could use a state management library such as Mobx (https://mobx.js.org) or Redux. Redux may be overkill if the app is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps pass it as a [navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop) using the `setParams` method.

An alternative, depending on the scope of your app, would be to look at a state library such as Redux or MobX - but if it's a small app, it's overkill

Comment: Yeah I've tried the setParams but I'm not sure I'm doing it in the correct way if you could show how it would work in this example that would be helpful. I've looked at redux but I'm not sure I quite need it for what I'm working on.

Comment: So I've now set up a simple store with MobX - which is all working fine. The problem I have is I'm still in the same situation. The root class which renders the tabs, is the provider and sets up the store can't edit the store values as the store isn't available to it. This is where I have to grab the name of the current tab. Struggling to understand how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html), you will have a store where you can put shared properties and values,

Then your components can connect to that store and bind its props with the chosen reducer(s) and dispatch actions..

Comment: Yeah that's why I was looking at redux

Answer (score 0):

this structure may work:

```
class Home extends Component {
    func(val) {
        this.setState({value: val});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Two func={(val) => this.func(val)} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class Two extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="set" onPress={() => this.props.func('data')} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the normal way of passing a prop to a child component if there parent  is rendering the child but that isn't the structure I have.