# How do I transfer an variable defined in one file to another file?(React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I use the number variable defined in home.js in another file?

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getData();
        this.state = {
          number:'0',

       };
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406903/react-native-pass-props-to-another-component), you can do it like this:

```js
class Home extends Component {
    func(val) {
        this.setState({value: val});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Two func={(val) => this.func(val)} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class Two extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="set" onPress={() => this.props.func('data')} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```